# Help with arranging the pages of a site(Mainly to deal with the links)

Tags: php, apache, apache2

There is a way I was thought to do things but I want to get a little bit advanced. To pass variables and stuff through links, i do this

```
http://www.fayimora.com/games.php?catID=8
```

That works fine but am working on a more professional site now and I think that won't be nice enough. I would prefer links like

```
http://www.fayimora.com/games/
```

I know that to achieve this I just need to create subfolders under the main folder and then rename games to index aswel.
Now the only problem is how do i pass variables? Like above i passed a variable catID with value 8. Now if i want to do this giving that i dont want to show the user the variabes been passed in the link, ow do i go about this?...

I know it might be a little bit complicated but i really need it..

I was told to look at [this site](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) >However I got stuck with this

> Thu May 19 15:00:28 2011] [warn] module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
>   httpd: Syntax error on line 127 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf:

Thanks for the help in advance and please tell me if something somewhere isin't clear
Thanks

Comment: I don't have time to look up or provide any examples but you should look into Apache's MOD_REWRITE. That can help you do what you're trying to do to get pretty looking URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have done this in the past.  This uses a `.htaccess` file and Apache's mod_rewrite module:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

These rules essentially state that, for any path to my server that is not a request to an existing file or directory, rewrite that path to go through index.php.  Thus, a request such as /games/8/ will now be passed as index.php?path=/games/8.  You can then parse this path in index.php and call the appropriate controller for your view.

Comment: Hello thannks but I tried it and it ddnt work. I created a .htaccess file in my site directory and placed the above script but it still ddnt work :( PLease help

Comment: sorry for the late reply...i dnt get any errors at it..it just doesnt work